# Date time parse exception in previously working code

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I have this code fragment which worked previously for half year ( I wrote it myself ).

Yesterday I received new laptop with windows 10 ( previously 8.1 ) installed the most recent Java JDK `jdk1.8.0_181` and this code stopped working with error.

Is it something I was missing for the whole time or there were some changes in java internal API ?

How I can fix it ? I believe it was written properly.

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '29-Apr-2010,13:00:14' could not be parsed at index 3
```

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PP_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss");
private static final LocalDate DATE = LocalDate.parse("29-Apr-2010,13:00:14", PP_FORMATTER);
```

Comment: " installed the most recent Java JDK `jdk1.8.0_181`" That is not the most recent JDK.

Comment: Something like `DateTimeFormatter PP_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss", Locale.UK)` will fix the problem, as to why it's changed, I don't know - but it's probably good practice anyway

Comment: @AndyTurner Obviously I was pointing to the most recent update to JDK 8, this is why I provided the version. It is the most recent version on oracle website.

Comment: Maybe new OS was installed with different default locale?

Comment: @Ivan Yes, exactly that, the default locale were changed, bringing back Locale to US and all formats resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

try to add `Locale.US`

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PP_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
```

otherwise, you maybe able to parse only numeric format for the month.